# Is there any recommended naming convention for the private member of the class

Tags: c#, .net

somebody like to use m***, someone like to use _***, is there any guideline of this?

Comment: I personally don't like naming conventions for this and use calling conventions instead, making sure to put `this.` when referencing member variables.

Comment: @Jeff: I agree, using `this.` is a great coding practice. :)

Comment: @Jeff, Lambert - Reshaper suggests to remove redundant this from any variable. Any idea why? Should I override that suggestion for some good reason?

Comment: @Unmesh: I don't know why. A lot of coding tools support various conventions but I don't necessarily think that makes them best practise. In the end, as long as you're consistent, that is what matters. Have your team agree to a standard and stick to it.

Comment: A nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've traditionally used camel-cased prefixed with an underscore (e.g., `_firstName`) but more and more I'm moving to [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) b/c there's less code clutter and 9 times out of 10 I don't need a private field.

```
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

Comment: I never quite 'got' what automatic properties were useful for until seeing this answer. I've only ever used them in interfaces to declare what properties the implementing class should implement, but still used private _* variables plus accessor properties in the class itself. +1 for making my code neater!

Comment: Their main reason is that they don't break existing compiled code if they're turned into regular properties -- but turning variables into properties does break code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are guidelines around this. You'll often find at least one in the company you work for, if it's an ISV. Sometimes more than one. Chances are it won't be adhered to consistently, unless you've got a good regime of code review and everyone understands the naming convention thoroughly.

There's no *one standard* naming convention for this - simply because the benefits of a worldlwide convention don't exist for *private* members in the way that they do for public members.

If I've got to use libraries from 5 different companies, it really, really helps me if they're consistent in terms of naming types, methods, even parameters. I couldn't care less what naming convention they use for their private members: whatever lets them write code as effectively as possible, basically.

Personally, I don't use any kind of prefix for private variables... but I've worked in companies which use `_`, and I've worked in companies which use `m_` or `s_`.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, it's a convention. I believe people from a C++ background use the m_* notation often, but I myself prefer the _* notation. There's no fixed rule though; consistency is the key. The one rule I always follow is making sure I use the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft recommendation is to use a leading underscore like: `_myField`.

But even they don't stick that convention.

Personally, I use a leading undrscore so that I don't have to qualify my variable names with `this.` and because it's easier to tell them apart from arguments.

Comment: You'd only have to qualify the variable name if you had a local variable or parameter in scope with the same name. That's usually for constructors, or property setters in Java.